# Seletively extract number from file name

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a list of files in the format as: `AA13_11BB`, `CC290_23DD`, `EE92_34RR`. I need to extract only the numbers after the `_` character, not the ones before. For those three file names, I would like to get 11, 23, 34 as output and after each extraction, store the number into a variable.

I'm very new to bash and regex. Currently, from AA13_11BB, I am able to either obtain 13_11:

```
for imgs in $DIR; do
LEVEL=$(echo $imgs | egrep -o [_0-9]+);
done
```

or two separate numbers 13 and 11:

```
LEVEL=$(echo $imgs | egrep -o [0-9]+)
```

May I please have some advice how to obtain my desired output? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `egrep` with `sed`:

```
LEVEL=$(echo $imgs | egrep -o '_[0-9]+' | sed 's/_//' )
```

Comment: Thank you! This produces the output needed. Could you explain the sed s command? I read from GNU documentation: the syntax of sed s command is ‘s/regexp/replacement/flags’. My understanding is sed 's/_//' therefore replaces underscore with empty character. How is it able to also trim the numbers before underscore?

Comment: @Muye It isn't, I'm only selecting the number after the `_` by using the pattern `_[0-9]+` in grep.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one `sed` using the regex `.*_([0-9]+).*` (escape it properly for `sed`):

```bash
sed "s/.*_\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/" <<< "AA13_11BB"
```

It replaces the line with the first [captured group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (the sub-regex inside the `()`), outputting:

```
11
```

In your script:

```
LEVEL=$(sed "s/.*_\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/" <<< $imgs)
```

**Update:** as suggested by [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), in both *BSD sed* and *GNU sed* you can shorten the command using the `-E` parameter:

```
LEVEL=$(sed -E "s/.*_([0-9]+).*/\1/" <<< $imgs)
```

Comment: @hjpotter92: If you want to remain POSIX-compliant, there's no way around escaping parentheses (and other ugliness). Otherwise, you can bypass this requirement in GNU Sed with `-r`, and in BSD Sed with `-E`. (GNU Sed also accepts `-E` as an alias for `-r`, but the caveat is that the regex dialect it supports differs from BSD Sed's.)

Answer (score 2):

To complement the existing helpful answers, using the core of [hjpotter92's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29504462/45375):

The following **processes *all* filenames in `$DIR` in a *single* command** and **reads all extracted tokens into *array***:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra levels < \
  <(printf '%s\n' "$DIR"/* | egrep -o '_[0-9]+' | sed 's/_//')
```

- `IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra levels` splits the input into lines and stores them as elements of array `${levels[@]}`.
- `<(...)` is a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) that allows the output from a command to act as an (ephemeral) input file.
- `printf '%s\n' "$DIR"/*` uses pathname expansion to output each filename on its own line.
- `egrep -o '_[0-9]+' | sed 's/_//'` is the same as in [hjpotter92's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29504462/45375) - it works equally on *multiple* input lines, as is the case here.

To process the extracted tokens later, use:

```
for level in "${levels[@]}"; do
  echo "$level" # work with $level
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep` with `-P` flag

```
for imgs in $DIR
do 
    LEVEL=$(echo $imgs |  grep -Po '(?<=_)[0-9]{2}')
    echo $LEVEL
done
```

Comment: Nice; you could also use `grep -Po '_\K[0-9]{2}'`. Do note, however, that `-P` (for Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions) is a _GNU_ Grep extension.